# Laravel Multi condition database update

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How to update database with multiple condition?

My Table name is work

```
+----+-----+
| id | num |
+----+-----+
| 1  | 56  |
+----+-----+
| 2  | 44  |
+----+-----+
| 3  | 85  |
+----+-----+
```

if input values are id=1,num=17

the table should be updated like this

```
+----+-----+
| id | num |
+----+-----+
| 1  | 17  |
+----+-----+
| 2  | 44  |
+----+-----+
| 3  | 85  |
+----+-----+
```

or if values are id=4,num=56

updated table should be like below

```
+----+-----+
| id | num |
+----+-----+
| 1  | 17  |
+----+-----+
| 2  | 44  |
+----+-----+
| 3  | 85  |
+----+-----+
| 4  | 56  |
+----+-----+
```

is there any Eloquent in laravel to update the table if not please give me a solution

```
$update=DB::table('work')
->updateOrInsert(['id'=>$request->MasterId,'Agent_num' => '$request->num',],['id' =>$request->MasterId, 'Agent_num'=>$request->$request->num]);
```

Comment: First, show your efforts please, dont expect directly a solution here,

Comment: This is not how SO works, first post some of your code/efforts.

Comment: $update=DB::table('work')
         ->updateOrInsert(['id'=>$request->MasterId,'Agent_num' => '$request->num',],
                 ['id' =>$request->MasterId, 'Agent_num'=>$request->$request->num]);

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use eloquent query to do this.

Here is a sample:

`$your_object->where('id','id_value')->where('num','num_value')->update(['num' => value_to_update]);`

Please from next time at least provide some code that you have tried so we can provide a better solution if needed.

Comment: I tried a code like below  $update=DB::table('work')
         ->updateOrInsert(['id'=>$request->MasterId,'Agent_num' => '$request->num',],
                 ['id' =>$request->MasterId, 'Agent_num'=>$request->$request->num]);

Comment: This is not an eloquent way. Please update your question with this code snippet. The solution I provided is the eloquent way in Laravel.

Comment: Updated , Sorry for my little knowledge am new in Laravel also in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

lets take a user table who's id is one and model named as User and you want to update his/her information like number/phonenumber at where user id is 4 can be done as following

```
User::where("id",4)->update( 'phone_number'=>'923069096975' );
```

In your case you can put your modal name at User and value of id at 4,column name at phone_number and value which you want to update, put at 923069096975.

this is a simple solution for your question

Comment: if you don't have value then you are not supposed to updated anything because you must have any value before you update anything. Value means the data that you want to replace to some previous thing.

Comment: if you dont have any value to update its mean you dont have to use update query

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple answer for this question.

```
Modal::where('id',4)->update([ 'num'=>56 ]);
```

Basically 4 and 56 can be stored in variables as well. This above query was like a reference. Let suppose we assign it to variables like as following

```
$id = 4;
$number = 56;
Modal::where('id',$id)->update([ 'num'=>$number ]);
```

This is a very simple answer.

If you have to update multiple rows to update against multiple IDs then just put the query in loop like following.

```
$idsArr = array(1,4,5);
$numArrays = array(56,44,67);
foreach($idsArr as $key => $id){
                                // Modal is Eloquent Modal
 Modal::where('id',$id)->update([ 'num'=>$numArrays[$key] ]);

}
```

Here we go.